# Creating, combining and caching lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

Say I have the following.

```
foreach (var loop in helper.Loop(x => x.LoopItems))
{
    loop.Text(x => x.Name);
    loop.Span(x => x.Name);

    foreach (var loopItem in loop.Loop(x => x.NestedLoopItems))
    {
        loopItem.Text(x => x.Age);
    }
}
```

This works just create with my current implementation, however it has to compile the inner lambda expression as many times as there are loop items. Currently this does something like this to create the expression to access a `List<T>` indexer. eg. `x.ListItems[i]`

```
var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(_expression, ((PropertyInfo) _expression.Member).PropertyType.GetMethod("get_Item"), Expression.Constant(i));
var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, T>>(methodCallExpression, _expression.GetParameter<TModel>());
```

It then does

```
var newExpression = CombineExpression(listExpression);
var enumerable = newExpression.Compile().Invoke(_htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
```

And it is the compile step that seems to be the expensive one.
Would there be any way to cache this given the fact that it needs to create a new one for each loop, such that `i` in `Expression.Constant(i)` needs to increment each time modifying the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what CombineExpression does but if you can change from `Func<TModel, T>` to `Func<TModel, int, T>` (assuming the indexer is always an int) if not you could add another generic to the method since you are already passing in "i" to get the Constant in the expression.

Also not entirely sure what type _expression is either so I don't know if this exactly is calling the overloads I think it is.

```
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "i");
var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(_expression, ((PropertyInfo) _expression.Member).PropertyType.GetMethod("get_Item"), parameterExpression);
var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, int, T>>(methodCallExpression, _expression.GetParameter<TModel>(), parameterExpression);
```

Then you could compile expression and get `Func<TModel, int, T>` and when invoking the Func you would pass in the "i" value.

Again since I don't know what CombineExpression does but if you get a strongly typed Func out of it you can just call it without the invoke.

Another side note why do expressions to get access to a list indexer?  Why not just use IEnumerable<> or worst cast if you don't know they type but need the objects cast to IEnumerable (non-generic) and iterate over that?